# Push Notification in Asp.net

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net

I am working on the Asp.net and want to send the push notification to iPhone using ASP.NET(C#).
How can I achieve this.Can you provide the detail on the same. I have little bit Knowledge about APSN-sharp",but I don't know how to user it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: DOES APN provide Rest(Http) protocole to send push notification ? to simplify your code in c# , use RestSharp to send rest request to APN

Answer (score 0):

[iPhone Push Notification server tutorial](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/). This is a php code. Hope this will help you to understand the logic and concept. So you can convert it into ASP C#.